# C#/WPF CollectionView - How to Add Items at Specific Position

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview

I'm working with **ListCollectionView** objects to display lists of items. Currently, I'm building a screen that has two of these lists - one, `completeList`, holds all available items, the other one, `sortedList`, holds a subset of them with the *item order* being relevant. Possible actions here are

- add or remove any of `completeList`'s items to/from `sortedList`
- move items up or down in `sortedList`
- save the content of `sortedList`.

Now, my question is this: **is there any possibility to insert items into `sortedList` at a defined position?**

Right now, they will always be added at the end of the list, regardless of the currently marked item, and I didn't find a way around it - apart from the obvious dirty hack, which would have me store all items after the desired position, remove them from the list, add the new item, then re-add all stored items in the correct order.

Does ListCollectionView offer any such functionality, or is there another CollectionView class that would do the trick?

Comment: Don't catch me on this - but cant you use List<T>.Insert for that ?

Comment: What type is sortedList? CollectionView is a view over a list. Insert into the underlying list, not the CollectionView wrapper.

Comment: You could craete a hidden OrderBy value, otherwise you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually asking for something that's a logical contradiction.  Suppose I have a `ListCollectionView`sorted alphabetically:

```
American
Continental
Festival
Imperial
Tower
Worldwide
```

Should I be able to insert `Luxor` between `American` and `Continental`?  Not if the view is sorted.  There's only one place that item can go.  And where it appears in the *view* is independent of where it might appear in the underlying *list*.

Without knowing more about your application, it's hard to know exactly what to suggest.  But if a collection view is sorted, the way to make an item appear at a specific place in the view is to assign its sort key(s) a value that will, once the view is refreshed, cause it to appear in the desired location.

A fairly trivial (and generic) way of doing this is to add a `DateTime` property to the data item class, set it to `DateTime.Now` in the item's constructor, and make it the last sort key that the view uses.  Then, when adding a new item, set its other sort key properties to the value of the currently selected item.  If you do this, new items will always appear in the appropriate place, so long as you don't change the values of any of the sort key properties.

Having said that, from the other features you want to support, I believe that you shouldn't be using a `ListCollectionView` at all for what you're calling `sortedList`.  This list isn't sorted.  It's *ordered*, which is not at all the same thing.  When the user moves an item up in the list, you actually want to change its position.

What you probably want to do is implement the list as an `ObservableCollection`, and wrap it in a view model class that exposes `Items`, `SelectedItem`, `AddNewCommand`, `MoveUpCommand`, `MoveDownCommand`, and `SaveCommand` properties.  Then you can bind the `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` properties of a `ListBox` or `ListView` to `Items` and `SelectedItem` properties in the class, and bind buttons or hyperlinks or whatever in the UI to the commands.  The commands will manipulate the `Items` property, using `Remove` and `Insert`, and since the `Items` is an `ObservableCollection`, the UI will stay in sync.

Comment: Right, how can you add at an index when you have a sort in place?

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, sorry 'bout that - I'm actually after a process of bringing items into a manually defined sequence here, so probably 'manual order' is the correct word. I'm going to try your suggestion of using an ObservableCollection and adding the item there. Thanks! :-)